# XML files with multiple namespaces - How to define valid locations when mixing them

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns:FB="http://blabla.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <Transaction>
    <RetailTransaction>
      ...
      <FB:Foobar>Allowed here</FB:Foobar>
      ...
    </RetailTransaction>
    <FB:Foobar>Not allowed here</FB:Foobar>
    ...
  </Transaction>
</POSLog>
```

POSLog/IXRetail is an industry-standard and I have no (reasonable) way to change the XSD or the XML I receive.
A vendor delivers XML files with a custom additional namespace (`FB` in the example).
They also deliver an XSD file which defines a whole bunch of elements like this:

```
<xs:element name="Foobar" type="xs:string"/>
```

Unfortunately, there is no connection between the two namespaces but in reality, these additional elements only have certain places where they can be used in POSLog (see the example).

Is there a way to create an XSD for the "FB" elements that limits where in the IXRetail namespace they can be used.

To sum it up:

I have

1. The XML file from above
2. The POSLog XSD
3. The Vendor XSD (`FB`)

The only thing I might be able to influence is *3*.

Elements defined in *3* are meant to *extend* (i.e. provide additional information for) certain elements from *2*.
Unfortunately, the way things currently are the places where elements from *3* can be used in *2* cannot be enforced/validated using the XSD.

I'm looking for a way to basically *extend* 2).

Comment: So you have two XSDs with their own target namespaces, and you'd like to design a new XSD that represents a mix of the two?   Yes, you can sometimes do that is about all we can answer.  The devil will be in the details, which are too lacking in your question to expect to be present in an answer.

Comment: @kjhughes I'd love to make the question better but I'm afraid your comments didn't help me understand what's vague about the question.

As mentioned:
I have 1) the XML file from above, 2) the POSlog XSD, 3) the vendor XSD

The only thing I _might_ be able to influence is 3).

Answer (score 1):

The structure that you are validating is a PosLog/IXRetail 'transaction'.

> these additional elements only have certain places where they can be used in POSLog

Does the POSLog XSD allow these extra elements to appear in these specific places? If it does, then the answer depends on exactly what that extension mechanism is. If it does not then the XML does not match the POSLog schema and is invalid.

> Is there a way to create an XSD for the "FB" elements that limits where in the IXRetail namespace they can be used.

No. A schema for the FB elements would describe the allowed names and contents of the FB elements. But it could never specify where they might be used in a completely different schema. So the 'where in the IXRetail' part will need to be specified in the POSLog xsd.

Comment: There are so many unknowns that you really can't say no or yes because you'd have to specify so many contingencies or assumptions that it's just not worth trying to answer such a vague question.

Comment: @kimbert Thank you for the answer, I'll try to clarify:

No, POSLog XSD has no knowledge whatsoever about the vendor elements/schema.

But I'm afraid you've confirmed what I already believed. I had hoped that there would be a mechanism to allow what I want.

A XSD can import another namespace and refer to those elements. So I had hoped I can basically "extend" an existing schema/elements.

Comment: Yes, you can extend an existing schema _unless_ the authors of the schema have purposely prohibited that. But then your schema would not be the standard POSLog/IXRetail schema. It would be a different schema, based on the original, owned and maintained by you.

Comment: Well, I just learned about `<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>` which does a small part of what I need